# How to use TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, .net, db2, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

I am trying to update a DB2 database (via NHibernate) under a distributed transaction but it keeps failing.

Here is the code I've written:

```
public bool ExecuteUsingDTC(List<Func<bool>> tasks)
{
    var result = false;
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
    {
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            //carry out db modification tasks
            tasks.ForEach(task => { result = result && task.Invoke(); })
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        scope.Complete();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I keep getting the exception:

```
NHibernate.TransactionException was unhandled by user code
Message=Begin failed with SQL exception
Source=NHibernate
StackTrace:
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.BeginTransaction()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.BeginTransaction()
   at DTCProofOfConcept_Repository.ExecuteUsingDTC(List`1 tasks) in C:\Project\Infrastructure\GlobalRepositories\DTCProofOfConcept_Repository.vb:line 20
   at 

InnerException: IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception
   ErrorCode=-2147467259
   Message=ERROR [HY011] [IBM] CLI0126E  Operation invalid at this time. SQLSTATE=HY011
   Source=IBM.Data.DB2
   StackTrace:
        at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.HandleError(IntPtr hHandle, SQL_HANDLE hType, RETCODE retcode)
        at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Transaction.set_AutoCommit(Boolean value)
        at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Transaction.BeginTransaction()
        at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.BeginTransactionObject(IsolationLevel isolevel)
        at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolevel)
        at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.BeginTransaction()
        at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.System.Data.IDbConnection.BeginTransaction()
        at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   InnerException:
```

Comment: I have been using the DB2 client for years without ever succeeding in using the TransactionScope. Had to create the transactions manually.

Comment: @JohannBlais how were you able to handle distributed transactions ?

Comment: no I was not. But it was not a mandatory feature for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using TransactionScope like this

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope(...))
{

    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Begins and commits a transaction for you.  If an exception is thrown then the transaction will be aborted by the scope being disposed without Complete being called.

I suspect your problem is that you have an additional explicit call to BeginTransaction/Commit.  Remove those and assuming NHibernate plays nicely with TransactionScope all should be fine.

Using TransactionScope may involve use of the distributed transaction co-ordinator (DTC).  If so you need to open Administrative Tools|Component Services.  Navigate to Distributed Transaction Coordinator|Local DTC. Right click, properties, security tab.  Enable security and as a start enable everything.  If this works read up on DTC security and reduce to a minimum.

Or as suggested by DanVallejo remove TransactionScope and just use your explicit transaction.

Comment: Thanks, even after using your code, I still get the exception : ERROR [HY011] [IBM] CLI0126E  Operation invalid at this time. SQLSTATE=HY011

Comment: Your note on DTC applies to the machine hosting the DB2 database, correct?

Comment: Probably, but it's a while since I had to configure DTC.  Could be client and/or server.

Comment: now that I think about it, I realize I have been playing with settings on the client machine, not on the DB2 server. maybe I need to change configurations on the DB2 server to enable XA transactions but it's a mainframe computer, not windows.

Comment: I think you're on your own now.  I've no experience of DB2.

Comment: DTC has to be configured on both the client and server computers for it to work.